# Boot windows 10 from m.2

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

I have a problem installing Windows 10 on an M2 SSD. The Windows installer detects my disk and installs the OS there, but on reboot it shows the message "insert bootable device and press any key". CSM, Secure Boot disabled, additional HDD I removed from my computer.The computer is new and nothing has been installed before. The above actions I did read other topics, but did not help me.

Motherboard: ASRock X570 Phantom Gaming 4;
SSD: A-Data XPG GAMMIX S11 Pro

Comment: CSM is incompatible with NVMe M.2 drives.  Why have you enabled CSM and disabled Secure Boot.  Windows 10 supports both.

Comment: @Ramhound I must have written it wrong, CSM disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your BIOS/UEFI if AHCI in SATA is enabled.

Comment: SATA controller set "AHCI"

Comment: @TyupkinV - That is to be expected since your storage devices are using GPT instead of MBR.  You can ignore this answer.  Didier erroneously submitted commentary as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinsert the removable medium you used to install Windows (USB drive?), let it uncompress Windows PE in RAM, then instead of installing again, choose Repair.

Go to Advanced, then Command line, and type the following:

diskpart (Enter)

list disk (Enter)

list volume (Enter)

If you get an error message at stage 2 (list disk), it means your SSD isn't recognized by the motherboard, for some reason. Maybe it's not properly seated in its connector, and has to be properly attached.

If you get to stage 3 (list volume), there should be a list of the volumes present on your SSD, beginning with number 0 (zero) for a small system partition, then on (1, 2, 3, etc...) depending on how many partitions Windows created upon install (usually only 2, sometimes 3).

System partition (your C drive, with Windows on it) should be either volume 1 or 2, but you have to check, based on the size of the volume.

Once you've listed your volumes, select the one with the biggest capacity: that's the one you want to fix the boot sector on.

Type "volume x active" (Enter) where x is the number of the partition where Windows is.

Exit diskpart (type "exit", then press Enter).

Once back at the prompt in Command line, type the following commands:

bootrec /fixboot (Enter)

bootrec /fixmbr (Enter)

bootrec /rebuildbcd (Enter)

If you don't get any error message after each command, type "exit", press Enter, and choose to restart your PC.

Comment: on step "volume x active" error "The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk."  Me need GPT, not MBR

Comment: What did the "bootrec /rebuildbcd" command return you?

Comment: I didn't use it after I got the error I wrote above in the comment. I'll give it a try.